# Получить исходный код страницы по URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

В php есть функция `file` которая позволяет получать исходный код страниц по указанному адресу. 
Мне нужно то же самое для `Javascript` (`Jquery`, `ajax`).

Чтобы был так ( если это возможно ):

```
<div id="image"></div>
<script>getContentOf('http://site.com/asd.html', myImage);
</script>
<script> document.getElementById('image')="<img src="+myImage[0]+">"; </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

[`кроссдоменные запросы ajax`](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B+ajax&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Comment: Уже искал, но везде требуется использование PHP скрипта, а мне нужен код без PHP.

Comment: Плохо искали.

Comment: @exec тогда мне тоже интересно. Прямой линк, пожалуйста

Comment: [нашел][1]
[1]:http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_1529.html

Comment: Если можно рабочий код дайте, а то с их примерами никак ни разберусь, и ссылки на проект из github битые.

Comment: проблема решена

Answer (score 0):

Ну еще можно попробовать вытянуть все содержимое BODY JS-функцией:

```
document.body.childNodes()
```

Comment: Можно и попробовать =)

Comment: Да, мы не против.